# Use v-if (with computed prop) inside v-for

Tags: vue.js

**Thanks for the help** with displaying the edit-button only when i'm logged in.

**The question I need help with is**: Can I bind the whole {{ project.* }} which im looping through? to the "EditProject" component?

```
<EditProject :project="`${project}`">
```

**Some info about my application:**
I am using Vuex to store all my data. *Ideally* I would like to just pass the hole project to the  dialog, but I could also just pass the ID and then load just that one project from Vuex. EditProject is a new dialog windows in which I would like to be able to edit the project.

I am creating a list of projects. The projects are stored with Vuex and Firebase, and are loaded as a computed prop.

```
computed: {
  projects () {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedProjects
  }
}
```

Then i'm looping through all the projects and display title, date, description and creatorId.

```
<v-list>
 <div v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
   <p>{{ project.title }}</>
   <edit-project v-if="isSignedIn === project.creatorId">
 </div>
```

Here comes the tricky part. I want to display  if project.creatorId is the same as the user logged in. "isSignedIn" is a computed prop:

```
isSignedIn () {
  if (this.$store.getters.user !== null &&  this.$store.getters.user !== undefined) {
    return true
  } else return false
},
```

Summary: The v-for loop contains a {{ project.creatorId }} which I want chech if is the same as this.$store.getters.user, And then display the "Edit-project" if match. Edit-project is a button that opens a dialog. This is a simplified version of my application.

I have tried v-if="checkUserIdMethod(`${project.id}`)", and all kind of variations, but had to resort to this website.  I'm pretty sure I could get it to work with them backticks ``

Comment: Return `user id` from `isSignedIn()` instead returning true / false

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to filter the list before rendering it like :

```
computed: {
  userProjects () {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedProjects.filter(p => p.creatorId === this.$store.getters.user.id   )
  }
}
```

If you use it in many components you can also make the filter in the store and call it like :

```
computed: {
  userProjects () {
    return this.$store.getters.userLoadedProjects(userId)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should be looking to compare the current users id, instead of building extra methods to find out if the current user matches based on `isSignedIn`, which means you could write:

`v-if="$store.getters.user.id === project.creatorId"`,

or alternatively refactor it into a separate method:

`v-if="isCurrentUser(project.creatorId)"`

```
isCurrentUser(creatorId) {
  return this.$store.getters.user.id === creatorId;
}
```

also, if you still need `isSignedIn`, I would simplify it to increase readability:

```
isSignedIn () {
  return this.$store.getters.user !== null && this.$store.getters.user !== undefined;
},
```